# Inserting special chars in flex web application in linux machines

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

We are implementing adobe flex application in linux machines. We need to use the keystrokes eg.,ALT+0151  to insert special charcters in to the application as it is in windows. Tried CTRL+SHIFT+U+Unicode, it works but it is interfering with the custom keyboard shortcuts we have added for the application. Is there any other way to implement this?